# Remove high-order polynomial trend from signal in Python

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a simple way to remove polynomial trend higher than order 1 (linear) from a signal?  Matlab's [`detrend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/detrend.html) accepts polynomial degree as an argument, but Python scipy's [`scipy.signal.detrend`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.detrend.html) only accepts "constant" or "linear" (order 0 or 1) as values of its `type` argument.

I can write my own detrender (similar to what is discussed [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/removing-non-linear-trends-from-timeseries-data-b21f7567ed51)) but would prefer to use implementation in an existing package for robustness.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What do your data look like? Is there anything to go on at all?